# Extending the scope of $index when using ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, dom

I need to use the value of the $index inside a ng-repeat directive out of its scope. I have tried a couple of workarounds but haven't been successful.

Here is my code:

```
<tbody ng-init="countObj={"count":0}" >
            <tr ng-repeat="data in result.data1" ng-init="index1 = $index" ng-if='result.data1'>
                <td>{{countObj.count = index1+1}}</td> // here I assing index1 to parent scope count
                <td>{{data}}{{countObj.count}}</td> // here count has the correct value
                <td>{{result.data2[$index]}}</td>                   
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="data in result.data3" ng-init="index2 = $index" ng-if='result.data3'>
                <td>{{index2+countObj.count}}</td> // here I add count to index2
                <td>{{result.data3[$index]}}{{countObj.count}}</td> // here count has no value
                <td>{{result.data4[$index]}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-if='result.data1 == undefined && result.data3 == undefined'>
                <td><strong>No data to display.</strong></td>
            </tr>
</tbody>
```

This complete table is inside a custom directive I have just posted the     tbody tag.

Directive is as follows:

```
<concept-details ng-repeat = "result in searchRes.list"></concept-details>
```

The data is rendering absolutely fine it is just the count which I am unable to get in the second tr tag.

I tested the above workaround on w3school and it works just fine.
Here is the code i tested:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>S No.</th>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody ng-init="count" >
    <tr ng-init="test = 5">
        <td>test is</td>
        <td>{{count = test}}</td>
        <td>end</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-init="test2 = 10">
        <td>test 2 is</td>
        <td>{{count + test2}}</td>
        <td>end</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I'm fairly new to angularjs so kindly excuse any mistake I might have made.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Code changed to Naveen Kumar's suggestion but still same output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ng-repeat scope creation works differently.
For each loop, ng-repeat creates a new scope, which inherits from parent 
but there's a catch here
If the property is primitive as count in your case it justs create a copy in the child scope.
The code of ng-repeat is as follows

```
      childScope = scope.$new(); 
      childScope[valueIdent] = value;
```

**count ($scope)
    copied to
  countCopy($childScope)**

So the increment on your count property is done on a local copy of count 
inside your first loop.

So all your increments are not reflected in the main count in your scope.
Workaround would be to make count as property inside an object.
If you change it to an object property then a copy of object would be made which 
would still have reference to the same main count property.

**countObj ($scope)
    copied to
  countObjCopy($childScope)**

both countObj and countObjCopy refer to same property count

```
   //while initializing
   <tbody ng-init="countObj={"count":0}" >

   //while incrementing 
   <td>{{countObj.count= index1+1}}
```

On further drilling down it seems there's more problem than caused due to child scope creation. I have commented on issue and its more related to angular
infinite digest error caused by updated scope variables inside view rendering.
Refer here for more https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

So the best approach would be to update count obj outside view content

One of the workaround is to use as follows is to update countobj's count in init of the first loop itself and use index to display

```
<tbody ng-init="countObj={'count':result.data1.length}" >
         <tr ng-repeat="data in result.data1" ng-init="index1 = $index"  ng-if='result.data1'>
            <td>{{index1+1}}</td> // here I assing index1 to parent scope count
            <td>{{data}}{{index1+1}}</td> // here count has the correct value
            <td>{{result.data2[$index]}}</td>                     
        </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="data in result.data3" ng-init="index2 = $index" ng-if='result.data3'>
            <td>{{index2+countObj.count+1}}</td> // here I add count to index2
            <td>{{result.data3[$index]}}{{countObj.count}}</td> // here count has no value
            <td>{{result.data4[$index]}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi @Naveen Kumar N, thanks for the help. But the solution you mention still gives the same output. The count in my second tr starts from 0. Please check the edited answer if anything seems wrong.

Comment: Hi droidArrh, i have digged further deep into your problem.
Essentially the piece of code which is causing problem is 
<td>{{countObj.count = index1+1}}</td>
It seems angular tries to update view each time count is updated this cause an error which is known as 
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

So apparently angularjs does n't allow to update scope varaibles inside rendereing of view.

Comment: Thanks @Naveen for the help. Your suggestion gave me the idea what I was doing wrong. Instead of assigning the count in the tr tag, I assigned it the length of the array in the tbody tag and it worked like a charm. Please edit your answer so that i can accept it as the right answer to the issue.

Comment: Thanks @DroidArrrh. This question helped me adding new parallels to my current base. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: We always learn by helping others and finding new challenges. Could you suggest some good resources from where is could learn angularjs in much more detail. I started learning angularjs basics from codeschool.

Comment: The best way to explore is to experiment and refer to the official docs. 
https://docs.angularjs.org/
And yeah ofcourse stack overflow too : P